# ChaiJS's expect gives an "undefined" error when using "to.deep"

Tags: mocha.js, chai

Any idea what's the difference between both tests ( or why the first one doesn't work ? )

```
expect([{ id: 1 }]).to.deep.include.members([{ id: 1 }]);
```

Gives the error:

```
TypeError: expect(...).to.deep is undefined
```

But this works:

```
expect([{ id: 1 }]).to.eql([{ id: 1 }]);
```

I'm using the browser's version by including:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jquery/jquery/2.1.4/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Automattic/expect.js/0.3.1/index.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.5.0/chai.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mochajs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/superagent/2.3.0/superagent.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works fine for me ([jsbin](https://jsbin.com/wuwecavomi/edit?html,js,console,output)).

Comment: can you paste a full example ? I don't understand where my issue is, remember I'm using the browser's version ( so the includes are different )

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "full example". It would be easier for you to show how you're using Chai, and break your code down to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Look at the "jsbin" link in my comment, that runs in the browser as well.

Comment: Ohh my eyes thought `jsbin` was a username lol sorry - I understand my problem now, since I've tried a copy-paste example from the web I had before including the "chai.js" an `Automattic/expect.js` included as well, and w/o knowing - I used `expect.js` vs `chai`, and `expect` really *doesn't have* a function called `deep`, removing that lib & using `var expect = chai.expect;` from your example fixed it. if you want to convert that to an answer - I'll mark it.

Comment: yep, you also answered my: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357931/chaijs-to-have-lengthof-is-not-a-function?noredirect=1#comment67970196_40357931 question :) thank you very much !

Comment: Since it's an issue that happened because of an incorrect configuration (so to speak), I don't think others will find it useful. Perhaps it's better to close your question instead of me answering it :D

Comment: at the end of the day I've copied it from the web ( didn't write it my own ) and since it didn't work - maybe others will find it useful